# Looking for device with following capabilities

Tags: tracking-devices

I'm looking for a device that has the following capabilities:

- min 50 Hz 3-axis accelerometer and 3-axis gyroscope
- bluetooth
- wifi
- programmable
- at least 1 Gb storage
- decent (rechargeable) battery (should be able to stream at least 20 hours of data)
- the smaller the better

I would be a plus, if it had any extra measuring capabilities (e.g. gps, temperature, magnetometer etc) had a sturdy casing and maybe a GSM module, but the main things are the ones I listed.

I've been looking around but haven't found one that could do all of these yet.

Comment: whats your budget? A phone maybe?

Comment: @Eumel that would be way too large. A smart watch would be better but those have a lot of things I don't need.